# Audio Player for AppleTV - TVML

Tags: javascript, tvos, apple-tv, tvml

does someone know a nice way to display a player with a picture, title and artist name for AppleTV?

I've tried with:

```
  videoURL = ele.getAttribute("videoURL")
  if(videoURL) {
    var player = new Player();
    var playlist = new Playlist();
    var mediaItem = new MediaItem("video", videoURL);
    player.playlist = playlist;
    player.playlist.push(mediaItem);
    player.present();
    player.play();
}
```

But nothing appear. Anyone to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Headline asking for audio, though you are setting up a `video` mediaItem.
Try using the `audio` item, filling the metadata to your liking.

```
// set up new mediaItem
var mediaItem = new MediaItem("audio");

// player data
mediaItem.url = ...
mediaItem.title = ...
mediaItem.subtitle = ...
mediaItem.artworkImageURL = ...
mediaItem.description = ...
```

See https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/TVMLJS/Reference/TVJSMediaItem_Ref/index.html as well.